# Changing the name of AutoGenerateSelectButton

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Using C# & ASP.Net

In my webpage am using gridview

Code.

In a GridView First Column is displaying as select option(name as "select") for each row, i want to change a name "Modify" instead of select.

How to change the name.

Comment: What about pasting aspx page code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the properties of your GridView isn't it. There you can change all the button's labels and styles.